# Open source code exists for ONVIF video stream on camera side? (not client side)

Tags: camera, ip, onvif

I would like to send a video stream via an ONVIF protocol from an a H.264 stream or an IP camera (which has not a onvif protocol).
I have seen that a [programmer's guide exists](http://www.onvif.org/Portals/0/documents/WhitePapers/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmer%27s_Guide.pdf) but does a open code exists in java, C, javasript,etc?

Comment: It's almost a year after your question and there are a number of ONVIF libraries in C++, Ruby, etc.  Github alone hosts several implementations: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onvif

Comment: It's really curious, yesterday you commented not to just post links as answers, today you post a link to github, pointing to a lot of empty repositories. Most of the implementations cover the client side, are incomplete and are not tested against the official test tool. Remember that every 6 months a new release of the standard is released, therefore you should really learn to deal with GSOAP instead of depending on outdated and mostly incomplete implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Such a code does not exist, because the specification is in WSDL form, so you can use that to autogenerate the code with an adequate tool such as [gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html).

**A note for comments**

I am part of the ONVIF group, I used to be part of PSIA and took part to ISO/IEC TC 79 WG 12 for 62676-2. I can say that, unlike PSIA, there is not official code for device or client. Further more, implementations made by companies selling SOCs exist, but they require NDAs and are not opensource.

Since implementation depends on the operating system of the camera as well as on the software used to implement it and on the hardware, they are too specific. The tool used by most manifacturers is GSOAP. So please:

1. Understand that the WSDL specifications together with the programming guide is sufficient to develop it
2. Stop adding meaningless comments and/or suggest edits just to get badges.

Comment: If you want your client to be general, there are a bunch of different versions of ONVIF specifications. So you have to use GSOAP to generate multiple versions of the massive quantities of header/cpp files and then perform version detection and use different namespaces and functions depending on the version.  Making a client that can support all ONVIF compliant cameras with GSOAP is not something you will finish in two weeks - you're looking at several months of tedious work trying to support every little nuance.