# ONVIF Sample NVT, NVR etc. code

Tags: camera, onvif

I have to implement camera systems that support ONVIF specification.
When I search "sample ONVIF code" through internet, I find the client side (ONVIF device manager written in C#) but no available sample for NVT NVR etc. Is there any example? The programming language is not important.

Perhaps this is the same question as:

[Open source code exists for ONVIF video stream on camera side? (not client side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806950/open-source-code-exists-for-onvif-video-stream-on-camera-side-not-client-side)

but there is no answer at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there's one opensource client, [OnvifDM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/).

Please pay attention that this program is not related to the ONVIF group, so you can use it as an example, but it is not the officially endoersed way to implement the protocol. The only official document is [Application Programmer's Guide](http://www.onvif.org/Portals/0/documents/WhitePapers/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmer%27s_Guide.pdf).

Finally, ONVIF has a [developer forum](http://developer.onvif.org/) where you can get lots of information. You don't need any more to be member of ONVIF to access it.

Comment: It seems that the developer forum is now closed only for ONVIF member domains

Comment: Also it's worth a mention that the guides aren't really up-to-date. I think the latest one is this one - genivia.com/dev.html (Notice it has some compilation errors in its examples)